# How to hide loader when form submission complete

Tags: jquery

I have a form which generates a PDF report. On submission of the form I applied a loader overlay and it works, but after downloading my PDF the loader is still visible. How can I hide the loader?

```
<form  method="POST" action="some action" id="generate_pdf_form">
  <input type="submit" class="pdf" value="GENERATE PDF">
</form>
```

```js
$('#generate_pdf_form').submit(function() {
  $.LoadingOverlay('show', { text: 'Processing request...' })
});

$.LoadingOverlay("hide")
```

I hide the loader on document.ready function also.

Comment: There's no way to know in client-side JS when a file download has been completed. If the processing which generates the PDF file is taking some time to complete (which would necessitate the loading overlay) then you may be better served by sending the form request using AJAX, then hiding the overlay when the request completes

Comment: So there is no way except AJAX request!!